# how to target a class within a variable using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, targeting

Not sure if I phrase the question correctly, but I'm trying to target a class within another class, but I've declared the parent class as a variable.

```
<div class="parent">
  <p class="child">hello world</p>
</div>

var a = $('.parent');
var b = $('.parent .child');
```

Is there a better way/convetion of declaring variable 'b'?
Or targeting classes within variable 'a'?

Comment: please do some *research* before asking. Start here: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to target elements inside of `a` you can use:

```
var b = a.find('.child');
```

Answer (score 2):

Since 'a' is now a jquery object, you can use the 'children' method to find a matching node:

var b = a.children('p.child'); or
var b = a.children('p');